# Scalable owner interface

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I am designing a simple city simulation in C# in which a city is a class. The city has a number of systems like a RoadSystem and TrafficSystem which are also classes.
The City class aggregates instances of the above classes.

```
class City: ICity
{
    RoadSystem.IRoadSystem       m_roadSystem;
    TrafficSystem.ITrafficSystem m_trafficSystem;
}
```

Example 'system' code:

```
class SimpleRoadSystem : RoadSystem.IRoadSystem
{
    public SimpleRoadSystem(ICity owner)
    {
    }           
}
```

The systems as well as the city itself have interfaces to allow alternate implementations as usual.

The classic problem I have is when instantiating the systems. Since the systems are owned by the city class I can pass a ICity instance to them. The ICity interface can be used by the system class to pull any required data from the owning city class. However this ties the SimpleRoadSystem to work with cities only. But in reality a road system is a generic idea, it can be used to implement the roads for a region or in a town which may have different interfaces. Basically tying the owner of the RoadSystem to be a City only, feels restrictive.

So the other idea is to have a IRoadSystemOwner interface between the city and the RoadSystem, which is implemented by the City.

```
class City: ICity, IRoadSystemOwner, ITrafficSystemOwner,......
{
    RoadSystem.IRoadSystem       m_roadSystem;
    TrafficSystem.ITrafficSystem m_trafficSystem;
}

class SimpleRoadSystem : RoadSystem.IRoadSystem
{
    public SimpleRoadSystem(IRoadSystemOwner owner)
    {
    }           
}
```

But this does not scale. The city can have any number of systems. Its actually a list thats loaded at runtime. So if the city has 10 different systems it needs, it will need to anticipate that beforehand and implement 10 different owner interfaces!!

Basically I am trying to figure out how to allow the RoadSystem owned class to have a owner which has a known owner interface for sure! 
But not implement this idea via non-scalable inheritance. This should allow the owned class to pull required information from its owner. It should scale well as a city can have any number of systems thats decided at runtime from data.

The way I see it dynamic casting or a generic property system seems to work. The RoadSystem class could try to cast the owner instance to a ICity or a ITown or IRegion and see which succeeds.
Or the owner has a getProperty(key) function which returns a generic object reference which can be cast to the concrete class to get to the actual data like say:

```
object obj = owner.getProperty("Map")
IMap map = obj as IMap;
if (map == null)
{                
    throw new System.ArgumentException("The map could not be retrieved from owner", "original");
}
```

Is there any other way than using dynamic casts?

Comment: This sounds like you need to implement a builder pattern. A builder pattern separates the construction from the representation. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Answer (score 1):

"The City class aggregates instances of the above classes" is the root of the issues here, as I see. Then you want a region class to aggregate the same, then you rethink the system in a way when 2 cities should have the same subsystem. This would lead to many complexity issues later.

Try to rethink this in a different way when the city doesn't know anything about the subsystems so they are independent and there is a class World/Execution context (which is a container for all of this and know everything about everyone).

I don't see any clue of how you would like to use that so I don't provide any "real" methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class World
    {
        public List<ICity> Cities { get; set; }
        public List<IRegion> Regions { get; set; }

        public List<IRoadSystem> RoadSystems { get; set; }
        public List<ITrafficSystem> TrafficSystems { get; set; }
        //any other systems you like

        public void AddRoadSystemToCity(IRoadSystem system, ICity city)
        {
        }

        public IRoadSystem GetRoadSystem(ICity city) //or any other rule we would like to use later
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public interface IRegion
    {
    }

    public interface ITrafficSystem
    {
    }

    public interface IRoadSystem
    {
    }

    public interface ICity
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> However this ties the SimpleRoadSystem to work with cities only. But
>   in reality a road system is a generic idea, it can be used to
>   implement the roads for a region or in a town which may have different
>   interfaces.

From your explanation it seems like you are after some kind of magical solution that would let a concrete class work with any collaborator types without crafting a common abstraction for those.

1. If `SimpleRoadSystem` needs to collaborate with different "owner" implementations it doesn't know about then I dont see any other way than constraining the relationship using an interface.
2. If you want `IRoadSystem` to be implemented for various kinds of disparate "owner" interfaces where each implementation only ties to a specific subset of such "owner" interfaces then what about `public class SimpleCityRoadSystem implements IRoadSystem<ICity>`.
3. Your current design assumes two-way relationships, which generally should be avoided. You haven't explained why `SimpleRoadSystem`needs to know about it's owner, but couldn't you redesign the system to that the "owner" tells `IRoadSystem` what to do and provides the necessary data instead of needing `SimpleRoadSystem` to know about it's "owner"?
4. If the communication & relationship between system components is extremely complex and needs to be very flexible then perhaps a message-passing design would be best suited, where all components sends & listens messages using a message bus.

   For instance, a `RandomTrafficSystem` could send a `(TrafficJamStarted congestionLevel=high)` message which could be handled by any interested party.

It doesn't help that we dont understand your problem domain at all. Rather than explaining your current model and it's flaws you should focus on explaining the details of the problem you are trying to solve. Perhaps an entirely different model would be a better fit (e.g. something ressembling a game model with a world, items (road-segment, car, etc.), coordinates, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is to develop your domain further and have some generic concepts that can be better shared throughout. For example, instead of an `IRoadSystemOwner`, which really doesn't feel like a domain concept, try to think of what a `RoadSystem` actually serves and you might come up with something like an `IAdministrativeDivision` or something else that better captures the intent of the design.

This is an application of the Interface Segregation Principle within Domain Driven Design, and the key is that it should feel natural for a *city* or a *region* to be an *administrative division*, for a *road system* to work with it, and for you to talk about those concepts on their own.

Comment: I dont think interface naming was at play here. The OP did not seem to want the relationship to be constrained on an interface at all, which doesn't make any sense the way things were explained as it's the only solution. My feeling is that we may have misunderstood the question or made wrong assumptions, hence why I proposed different strategies in my answer. I'm a huge fan of DDD myself btw ;)

Comment: @plalx: I'm not just proposing an interface name change here, but that the domain be developed further, so that new concepts with their unique and cohesive interfaces emerge. That's what I meant with "generic concepts that can be better shared throughout". Sorry I wasn't that clear.

Comment: Well, searching for a better name implies searching for a better concept. It could be the right path, but the OP did not seem to want to go down that road. With the little we know about his problem domain it's not easy to propose a solution.

Comment: A good solution would be approached by following good principles. It's a journey, not a destination.